# WSS 3.0: Email notification/alert on download

Tags: sharepoint, wss-3.0

Is there a way in WSS 3.0 to send an email notification when a list attachment is downloaded or when a document in a document library is downloaded?

Comment: if anyone cares, one solution laid out here @ http://www.lukehutton.net/blog/2011/02/22/sharepoint-email-notificationalert-on-download-of-list-attachment-or-document/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event listeners you can attach to list items in WSS only apply to add, update and delete events.

You'd have to map an HTTPHandler to the URL of the list/library storing the content.

This handler would be responsible for sending notifications when it's detected that a client is making a request for an attachment or document.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I won't be implementing this for a while, just getting a feel for it, so I can mark as answered later if it works out. My last requirement is to get the user who is downloading it, that should be doable in the handler as well you think? Thx

Comment: You can definately get the current user, you'll just need to make sure that you make a reference to the Microsoft.Sharepoint dll, and use the static property:  SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser

Comment: I'll keep an eye on this question in the future, you can update the question with any problems you have

Comment: Thanks Pierreten, I appreciate it, I'm going down that route starting in about 2 weeks.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to leverage SharePoint Auditing. SharePoint auditing can log whenever someone accesses an item.  If you had a process monitoring and querying the SharePoint Audit Log you could fire off your alerts.